# Проблемы с меню на CSS

Tags: html, css

Утро всем доброе.
Делаю меню на CSS, столкнулся с проблемами:

1.Не получается закруглить края у меню, с помощью **border-radius: 3px;** получается вот так:

[image: img]

2.Не получается с помощью **z-index** вывести выпадающее меню на задний план
 3.Когда применяю элемент **hover** к выпадающему меню  - цветом выделяются почему то только буквы.

Меню оригинал, которое пытаюсь скопировать - http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/blue-drop-down-menu#

CSS меню, то что уже сделал:

```
/*---------------------*/
#menu125,#menu125 li ul{margin:0px; padding:0px;list-style:none;}

#menu125 > li{
  float:left;
  width:auto;

}

#menu125 li ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
  width:auto;
}
#menu125 li:hover ul{display:block}


/*---------MAIN MENU------------*/
#menu125 > li{
  background: #3b5998;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0px solid #2b4479;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(2, 2, 2, .25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(2, 2, 2, .25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(2, 2, 2, .25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(2, 2, 2, .25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(2, 2, 2, .25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);

  text-align:center;
  padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;



}
#menu125 > li:hover{
  background: #2f4b87;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #1f325d;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #1f325d;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #1f325d;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #1f325d;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #1f325d;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
  -o-transition: all ease .3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .3s;
  transition: all ease .3s;
  }

#menu125 > li > a{
    padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
  -o-transition: all ease .3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .3s;
  transition: all ease .3s;

}

/*---------SUB MENU------------*/
#menu125 li ul{
   background: #3b5998;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0px solid #2b4479;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(2, 2, 2, .25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(2, 2, 2, .25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(2, 2, 2, .25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(2, 2, 2, .25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(2, 2, 2, .25), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);


   padding: 10px 60px 10px 10px;
  width: auto;
    height: auto;

   line-height: 40px; /* вертикальное расстояние между строчками */

 margin-top: 10px; /* позиционирование меню */
 margin-left: -15px;




 }
#menu125 li ul li{
  text-align:left;
 padding: 0px;



}
#menu125 li ul li a{

  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
  -o-transition: all ease .3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .3s;
  transition: all ease .3s;




}
#menu125 li ul li a:hover{

background: #2f4b87;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #1f325d;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #1f325d;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #1f325d;
    -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #1f325d;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #1f325d;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .3s;
    -o-transition: all ease .3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease .3s;
    transition: all ease .3s;




}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш пример. Поместите его сюда: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

1) Можно реализовать с помощью псевдоклассов:

```
#menu125 li:first-child {
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

#menu125 li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

2) Зачем выводить подменю на задний план?

3) Выделяются только буквы из-за того, что стиль применяется к тегу `<a>`, а он строчный. Его надо сделать блочным `display: block;`